# How to convert object to string with comma?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

This is php code.

```php
$demo = [{"value":"red"},{"value":"green"},{"value":"blue"}]
```

i need data like this:

```php
$demo = "red,green,blue"
```

The code will run in the Laravel controller.
Please Help me.

Comment: That's not valid PHP. If that's a JSON string, then it needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that is supposed to be a JSON string:

```
$vals = collect(json_decode($demo))->pluck('name')->join(',');
```

If that is just you describing how an array of arrays or objects looks when you return them (get converted to JSON):

```
$vals = collect($demo)->pluck('name')->join(',');
```

Just one way to go about it using Collections to help.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections)

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```php
$demo = [{"value":"red"},{"value":"green"},{"value":"blue"}]
```

is a not valid PHP code.

I assume it is a JSON string and then you can do it like so:

```php
$demo = '[{"value":"red"},{"value":"green"},{"value":"blue"}]';

$json = json_decode($demo);

$data = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->value;
}, $json); // This is now array of values, ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON, loop through the array to build the string you want. Perhaps easier to understand.

```
$demo=[{"value":"red"},{"value","green"},{"value"},{"blue"}];
$decoded=json_decode($demo);
$str=current($decoded)->value;
while($key=next($decoded))
    $str.=','.($key->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use implode!

docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```php
$array = array('1'=>'red', '2'=>'green', '3'=>'blue');
echo implode(",", $array);
// output -> red,green,blue
```

#### my test:

```php
uvulpos@Timvpos:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $array = array('1'=>'red', '2'=>'green', '3'=>'blue');
php > print_r($array);
Array
(
    [1] => red
    [2] => green
    [3] => blue
)
php > echo implode(",", $array);
red,green,blue
php >
```